# Can I ask about product requirements on European Standards?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I am a novice engineer with the task of making CE marked products. Unfortunately I am being lost in directives and often I don't understand which standards and directives apply to my product. I want to get help but it seems that these are too legal to write on electronics.se, and too technical to write on law.se. Can I ask these on electronics.se?

Comment: Given the wide range of products covered, try and determine the *classification* of your product as just what standard applies is to a great extent reliant on that classification.

Comment: Directives look huge and unclear. Don't try to read them. Just apply elementary safety, RoHS/lead free, eliminate electromagnetic emissions if any, quality connectors and other common sens stuff and it will likely pass the CE test.

Comment: IEC directives make up for crazy reading, I think it's all a big scheme to make money because the only people that can understand the requirements are them. I also love the mulit hundred dollar price tags for their documents

Comment: Can you provide some details and specs about your product without disclosing proprietary information?

Comment: Hello, I asked the question and got my answers. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/421495/94481 Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Go ahead and post your questions.  We've had a good number of questions about [ce](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ce), IEC, [ul](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ul), [fcc](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fcc) requirements.  They weren't badly received, typically.

Answer (score 4):

Such questions are on-topic, as long as they are related to electronic design. This includes questions about directives/regulations regarding:

- EMC
- Radio
- Electrical safety
- Low-voltage/high-voltage directives
- Electronic environment, ESD and water protection etc
- Environmental impact, RoHS, WEEE etc.
- Domain-specific electronic standards. Maritime, aerospace, automotive, EX zones, military etc.
- Manufacturing/soldering of electronics in regards to all of the above.